# SAS JavaOBJ not finding CLASSPATH

Tags: java, sas, classpath

I've got .jar classes I want to use in a SAS data step. They compile and test fine, I've placed them in c:\javastuff\MyClass.jar. Then, in the SAS config file I've tried adding -set CLASSPATH C:\javastuff\MyClass.jar to the file, and tried adding it to Dsas.app.class.pth. Finally, I've attempted the %macro solution on the SAS website that in theory, allows for dynamic updating of the CLASSPATH.

I keep getting the error message "Could not find class MyClass at line X column Y. Please ensure that the CLASSPATH is correct."

When I run Proc JavaINFO, it shows the classpath as C:\progra~1\SAShome\SASVER~1\eclipse\plugins\SASLAU~1.jar

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the java.library.path property? Check your library path using...System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

Answer (score 2):

You may need to bounce the server to pick up the option.  You can also try the following in your session:

`OPTIONS SET=CLASSPATH "C:\progra~1\SAShome\SASVER~1\eclipse\plugins\SASLAU~1.jar";`